# How can I compare images (caching images)?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm doing simple image caching in my metro style application. Here is what I've already done:

```
    private async void GetImage()
    {
        bool isFolderExisting = true;
        bool isFileExisting = true;
        StorageFolder storageFolder = null;
        StorageFile storageFile = null;

        // get screenshots folder    
        try
        {
            storageFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFolderAsync("screenshots");
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            isFolderExisting = false;
        }
        // if folder doesn't exist, create new one
        if (isFolderExisting == false)
            storageFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFolderAsync("screenshots");

        // get screenshot
        try
        {
            storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(this.LinkId);
            //IAsyncAction threadPoolWorkItem = ThreadPool.RunAsync((source) => { updateImage(storageFile); });
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            isFileExisting = false;
        }

        // if file doesn't exists, download and save new one
        if (isFileExisting == false)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(WebServiceAddress + "/screenshot/" + this.LinkId, UriKind.Absolute);
            var thumbnail = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(uri);
            storageFile = await StorageFile.CreateStreamedFileFromUriAsync(this.LinkId, uri, thumbnail);
            await storageFile.CopyAsync(storageFolder, storageFile.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }

        //this.ImageSource = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///temp/screenshots/" + this.LinkId)); 
        this.Image = "ms-appdata:///temp/screenshots/" + this.LinkId;
    }
```

Now I have to take care of the last part which is comparing images.
I'm checking if image exists in temp folder. If it doesn't exists I'm just downloading new, but if exists I need to check if it's the same as on server. How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetBasicPropertiesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getbasicpropertiesasync.aspx) method on the StorageFile class.  The [BasicProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.basicproperties.aspx) object includes a DateModified property that you could use to compare between the client and server.